# AIR application update itself?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5, flex4.6

How to make AIR application update itself with newer version ?

( AIR on Android and iOS )
( Flex 4.6 )

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you done some research, or some thinking on your own ? StackOverflow isn't really about finding solutions for you.

Comment: Have you searched on Google?  I know there are plenty of discussion / blog posts on such approaches.  Generically; you check a version number of the app with a version number from a remote server.  IF they don't match, then update the client.  https://www.google.com/search?q=Update+an+AIR+Application&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a large amount of tutorials available how to let air update itself. These are all focusing on desktop applications.

You are asking for an auto-update feature for Android and iOS. Android and iOS have their own update mechanics. If you launch a new version on the app store the app store or play store should handle the update. It is not possible to let adobe air update itself on those mobile operation systems as this would create a possible security issue.